# No such table error or the file is not a database

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've created a database called dbs with `SQLiteStudio` and then changed its extension to `.db` because the program can only save in `.sql` or others. Then I loaded it into my Assets folder.
I have the class of my DB connection:

```
public class db : Interface1
{
   public SQLiteConnection ConnettiDB()
    {
        var dbs = "dbs.db";
        var dbpath = (System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData));
        var path = Path.Combine(dbpath, dbs);
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

This code is ran into the `MainActivity.cs`

```
    public void EstraiDB()
    {
        string dbName = "dbs.db";
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), dbName);
        
        if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(dbName)))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int len = 0;
                    while ((len = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        bw.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The class of my database unique table is this

```
public class Table
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Indirizzo { get; set; }
    public string Civ { get; set; }
    public string Città { get; set; }

}
```

Now in the `SecondPage.cs` I run this code just to try if everything works well

```
        string dbName = "dbs.db";
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), dbName);
        using (var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            var cmd = new SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn);

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table";
            var r = cmd.ExecuteQuery<db>();
            ListView lstDB = v.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstDB);
            List<string> file = new List<string>();
            file.Add(r.ToString()); ;
            lstDB.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Application.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, file);
        }
```

The error is here `var r = cmd.ExecuteQuery<db>();` saying "no such table" and sometimes it says "file is not a database". I think the problem is around the db path but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: There is no code to insert `Table` in the database

Comment: but the db has already a table. Anyway how to do this?

Comment: it continues saying file is not a database

Comment: I thought you should have passed _cmd.ExecuteQuery<Table>_ not <db>

Comment: Stupid error. Now it says file is not a database

Comment: an Android asset is NOT a file.  Assets are read using AssetManager, not using File IO.  You need to copy your db from Assets and write it to the folder first, then you can open it with SQLiteConnection

Comment: yes, I do it with the code in MainActivity but keeps saying file is not a database

Comment: Have you confirmed whether the value of dbPath is the path to your db file?